# Sorting fomulas in an Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

For my project I need to arrange locations based on the lowest driving time to different locations. I simulated the driving distances (Row D, E & F), but the height depends on the products which are inputted in the different levels. The formula takes the driving distance (D, E & F) and height (Row G) and calculates the driving times (Row L, M & N).

I now want to sort the driving time results so I can input the products, but this ruins the table as the formulas will give errors. How can I make it so that the table can sort by times without ruining my formulas?

Picture one shows the table, which is 6000+ cells long (so manually typing it is not an option)

[image: Table overview]

Picture two shows the formula for the time, it basically rounds up the result on three decimals (AFRONDEN = ROUNDING) and uses if formulas to check if the height is zero, making it a floor level, or higher, making it a location in the air.

[image: Time formula]

Picture three shows what happends when the formula is sorted, it basically gives the "Value" and "Reference" error.

[image: Error after sorting]

These are the formulas in row G

[image: Formulas in row G]

I hope anyone can help me fix this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your Col G (Height) has a formula that is dependent on either the row values above or below the current row (my guess).  This would cause them G to recalc every time there is a sorting of the table. A REF error would mean that the sorting caused G to reference a non-existing cell.  The VALUE error could result from an internal formula calculation problem caused by the mis-referencing. The error in G would cascade into N (and it looks like M & L.

With the advantage of your comment, here is another approach:

**Method1**

Not knowing your formula in G, could you create it one time and then copy/paste-as-value where it is?  It would not recalculate each time it is sorted, but if that is acceptable, it would fix the problem.

**Method2**

You could create a SortKey for your original sort order.  This would allow you to maintain the referencing that you start with.

> One caution: you will be replacing direct cell references with XLOOKUP or INDEX, so this could really slow down your workbook with 6000 rows, but let's see...

Here is a simplified simulation of your worksheet:

[image]

The formula in **G** is dependent upon same row data from the **[Other stuff]** column as well as above and below rows from columns **I** (Other stuff) and **K** (Act Height).  If you sort this, it will generate garbage.

So now I will introduce a new column to the table called **SortKey** which simply holds an enumeration of the rows in their original order.

Now the table looks like this:

[image]

The new formula in G replaces the direct references to columns I and K with an XLOOKUP that searches for the SortKey +/- 1 and returns the corresponding values in I and K.  So we converted this formula in G:

```
=( [@[Other Stuff]] - N( I5 ) )
  / ( N( I7 ) - [@[Other Stuff]] )
  / ( N( K5 ) + 1 )
```

to this one:

```
=( [@[Other Stuff]] - N( XLOOKUP( [@SortKey]-1, [SortKey], [Other Stuff] ) ) )
   / ( N( XLOOKUP( [@SortKey]+1, [SortKey], [Other Stuff] ) ) - [@[Other Stuff]] )
   / ( N( XLOOKUP( [@SortKey]-1, [SortKey], [Act Height] ) ) + 1 )
```

When you sort it, the values in G are preserved:

[image]

But notice the N/A errors in G - this is because the XLOOKUP tries to reference a SortKey value that does not exist. Either it referenced a row below the last row or a row above the first row.  To prevent this, you need to tell XLOOKUP what value to deliver when this happens.  It is the 4th parameter - I left it blank here.

**Method 3**

You could sort the columns in their original order and then select Column G and do a REPLACE ALL to change K to K$ (assuming that you have no other words in the formula that have a K, such as KOLOM or TEKEN).  This would be a way to do mass editing to create the equivalent of F4ing your way to happiness.

That's all I can think of.

Comment: Yes that indeed is the case, the formula adds the height from three cells above (still row G) to the height from the product which is inputted, in row K. So if I understand you correctly, making the formula in row G with fixed cells using '$' will most likely solve the issue? 

The only question I would still have is how do I make these cells fixed? Using F4 on 6000 cells is possible but a lot of work, is there a faster method?

I included a screenshot of row G in the post

Comment: I can see how that would be really hard to implement - it would solve the problem.  Let me propose another approach by editing my response.  Normally, I would not have proposed an answer - I would have posted a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do that. Now that you upvoted my answer, I do.  The gamification on stack is annoying AF. Give me a min and I will have id ready.

Comment: Thanks, the explaination was very clear and the pictures helped a lot. I am still having difficulty finishing the assignment, as it still is a lot of manually work. I am going to create a new post regarding this problem, if you have any ideas on how to make it more efficient, I would greatly appriciate it!